# Cannot import Amazon DynamoDB into android?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, android-studio, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb

so I'm trying to set up an Amazon database and im following the tutorial for set up here : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/getting-started-store-query-app-data.html

But none of the imports work! When i import the following:

```
    import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.*;
    import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.*;
    import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBAttribute;
    import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBHashKey;
    import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper;
    import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBScanExpression;
    import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBTable;
    import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.PaginatedScanList;
```

Here is my dependencies:

```
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.3.3'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognito:2.3.3'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.3.3'
    compile('com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-mobileanalytics:2.3.3')
    compile('com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-apigateway-core:2.3.3')
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognitoidentityprovider:2.3.3'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an old thread, but for those reading this question, now you can use the AWS SDK for Kotlin to create Android Apps that can invoke AWS Services including Amazon DynamoDB. For details, see:

[Creating your first Native Android application using the AWS SDK for Kotlin](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/.kotlin_alpha/usecases/first_android_app)

Answer (score 1):

Since the dynamoDB is at the com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb:2.2.+.
If you want to use dynamoDB mapper class to use POJO, you need to import
com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb-mapper:2.2.+.

so use this instead

```
 compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.2.+'
 compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognito:2.2.+'
 compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognitoidentityprovider:2.2.+'
 compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb:2.2.+'
 compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb-mapper:2.2.+'
```